# Is there anything similar to HTML entities in Android

Tags: android, string

when I try to add string in string resource which contains a value of 1 -50, it is showing the following error

```
Replace "-" with an "en dash" character (–, &&;#8211;)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that is a typo in your question, but in your strings.xml you can use &#8211; this will be treated as in HTML.

Comment: it worked, in HTML we have entities, for this purpose. what are these called in android developement(&#8211;) and can i have the reference page for these.